# EF Code First foreign key definition / left join / navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda, foreign-keys

Let's say I have 3 tables:

```
[Table("Comments")]
public class Comment {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Users")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[Table("Users")]
public class Users {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

[Table("CommentAgree")]
public class CommentAgree {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Users post comments and other users can 'agree' with that comment, a bit like Facebook's 'like' system. I'm using lambda for my queries and I can do:

```
var query = db.Comments.Select(c => new {
            c.Id,
            c.Users.UserName,
            c.Text
});
```

How can I create a join to CommentAgree on `Comment.Id = CommentAgree.CommentId`? I could write the join in Lambda but I need it to be a left join as nobody may agree with the comment but I still want it to display.

I want to do it the right way, so I'm open to suggestions whether to do it by foreign keys, lambda joins, navigation properties... or something else?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is probably to use the features of Entity Framework and create navigation properties rather than explicitly using LINQ to perform the joins just for related data.

If your types are shaped just for the purposes of data access, then adding navigation properties to both ends of the relationship is probably a good idea, along with the foreign key properties that you already have.

The collection navigation property on `Comment` should implement `ICollection` (for example `List<CommentAgree>`), and you would have a reference navigation property of type `Comment` on the `CommentAgree` type.

You would then have to define the relationships in your mappings, either using data annotations or (preferably) the fluent API.

To load the related data, you could either use lazy loading, or eager loading (using the `Include` extension method), or use explicit loading from the entry information for the entity.

Comment: Hmmm ok, I've added a public List<CommentAgree> (I forgot to mention I have an FK from CommentAgree to Comment). And then in my lambda I can do c.CommentAgrees.Count() and this gives me exactly what I want! I think that sorts me but I will look into mapping it properly as I have not done that before, will check out the Fluent API. Thanks for your help